# Toggle on remote link

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a link which retrieves data and shows all details, which works fine.
However, I want it to act like a toggle, where it removes the details after a second click. It also should not send the ajax request to the server.

Maybe some state should be saved to know to either show the details or remove them? What is the best way to do this? This is the link:

```
= link_to "details", testitemlogs_path(testitem_id: testitem.id), remote: true
```

Comment: What does 'shows all details' mean? It populates a form? And you want to clear it? Or something else?

Comment: can you please explain what do you mean by remove, just clear HTML or need to delete record from table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with little javascript.

```
= link_to "details", testitemlogs_path(testitem_id: testitem.id), remote: true , id:'details-button'

$('#details-button').click(function(e){
    if($(this).hasClass('data-fetched')) {
      $('#target_div_id').remove(); //You can do whatever you want like hide or remove it from page
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
     }
  $(this).toggleClass('data-fetched');
 });
```

This script toggle `data-fetched` class on the anchor and check if that class exists then dont fetch data and hide/remove the target div.

Change `target_div_id` with actual container id which you wanna hide

Comment: I like this approach, I didn't know about the stopPropagation function, really interesting, thanks!

Comment: Well I am glad I could help you. stopPropagation  prevents event to bubble up to dom tree. you can find more details at https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done with the help of jQuery/Javascript.
Initially, you can show the `link_to` button as you are having right now on page load.
By clicking on the `link_to`, you should also hide the current `link_to` button and show another button with different id.
Then by clicking on the other button, you can hide the details form of your page.